# Unable to resolve service for type 'Volo.Abp.MultiTenancy.ICurrentTenant' while attempting to activate '...Controller'

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly, multi-tenant, abp

I get error:

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Volo.Abp.MultiTenancy.ICurrentTenant' while attempting to activate '...Controller'.
```

I enabled Multitenancy in my application and everything is good Until I want to get IcurrentTenant.Id and Name, So I injected ICurrentTenant in the controller and expected it to work because I configured it like so:

```
builder.Services.Configure<AbpMultiTenancyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.IsEnabled = true;
});

builder.Services.Configure<AbpTenantResolveOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AddDomainTenantResolver(builder.Configuration["App:SelfUrl"]);    
});
//builder.Services.AddScoped<ICurrentTenant, CurrentTenant>();
```

If I enable the commented line I get another error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 

'Volo.Abp.MultiTenancy.ICurrentTenantAccessor' while attempting to activate 

'Volo.Abp.MultiTenancy.CurrentTenant'.
```

I can verify that the Host name is correct in the api methods using HttpContext.Request.Host thus multitenancy is enabled:

```
en.localhost:44367
```

I want to use ICurrentTenant but I get errors, How to enable this?

Comment: The services are all contained in AbpMultiTenancyModule,try start the app follow this document:https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Application-Startup

Comment: Can you add more information like which controller are you trying to resolve; what type of application are you using (separate authserver or non-tiered)? Is your controller extending `AbpController`?